# Specify variable in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

probably been asked before but I couldn't find an answer.

Is it possible to specify a user defined variable in a mySQL query.  Such as:

`select * from table where column like "%MYVAR%" or column like "%MYVAR%"`

Basically, it would be a bit more complicated than that but if I wanted to use the same text multiple times how could I set this and reuse it?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is meant by `user defined variable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible -

```
SET @var1 = 'table%';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE @var1;
```

More information - [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: Thank you for that. In SQLyog I have to run the SET command first and then, separately, run the query (using 2 different query windows).  Can this be done from the same query window?  Not essential, but would cut a few clicks out.

Comment: You can do it in dbForge Studio for MySQL (free express edition) - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/

Answer (score 0):

To get this working, you should use stored procedure. Check [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html)